# WARNING ITMS-90737:

Tags: xcode

Этой ошибки у меня не когда не было. Вот только сегодня появилась.

> WARNING ITMS-90737: "Invalid Document Configuration. Document Based Apps should support either the Document Browser (UISupportsDocumentBrowser = YES) or implement Open In Place (LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace = YES/NO). Visit https://developer.apple.com/document-based-apps/ for more information."

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы исправить:

Открой Info.plist файл.

- **Если** ты используешь **UIDocumentInteractionController** в своем приложении, тогда добавь "UISupportsDocumentBrowser" со значение true
- **В другом случае**: добавь значение: "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" со значением true

**Info.plist** Code

```
//if using - UIDocumentInteractionController
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
    <true/>

//if not use - 
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
```

- Оригинал статьи: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262366/warning-itms-90737-invalid-document-configuration
- Чуть больше информации: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227696/app-store-connect-warns-invalid-document-configuration

Comment: то и другое добавляю выдает ошибку

Comment: @BlackDolphin Так я поэтому и написал, что надо одно из двух. )

Comment: я попробовал по одному и то и другое

Comment: @BlackDolphin Ошибка та же самая? Вы в коде на самом деле оба используете или только один из них?

Comment: у меня музыкальное приложения с браузером , раньше такой ошибки не было

Comment: @BlackDolphin Я думаю тип приложения не влияет. Тогда я пока не могу помочь. ( Найду что-то - отпишу тут.

Comment: может я что то не так делаю , сможете по скриншоту сказать куда именно что делать  .

Comment: @BlackDolphin Думаю да, но скриншот добавьте в описание вопроса.

Comment: сможете по teamviewer  подключиться ?

Comment: @BlackDolphin нет.

Comment: получилось ) спасибо большое за помощь )

Comment: А что именно было не так? Можете отписать?